# Making a simple assembly emulator

Tags: assembly, antivirus, virus, disassembly

I am working on project that is **detecting unknown Viruses**, so I am going to build my **small emulator** that emulates the assembly code of the executable so I can detect whether it is a virus or not by emulating it to virtual registers then observing what happens.
so I need help in getting the code of every assembly instruction in **c** .

Comment: If you ask like this, I can only recommend you to work on some simpler project and learn.

Comment: And what have you done so far?

Comment: How do you expect to detect a virus by examining the registers?  AFAIK, the most advanced antivirus programs use definition files of known viruses.  "Automatic" detection of previously uncategorized viruses would require artificial intelligence.

Comment: This sounds like a homework question -- implement a basic x86 emulator using C.

Comment: Good luck with this!  I remember a company doing this back in the early '90s (a friend of mine was involved in the testing of early development versions).  I believe the AV software was known as Victor Charlie.  Since they don't seem to be around anymore I'm guessing that this is MUCH harder to implement than it might appear...  I mean, if we can't even determine programmatically if a given code sequence ever "finishes", correctly determining malicious intent seems to also be impossible.

Comment: My aim is to observe the calls and the Registers change, then i could tell it it harms the computer or not. as if i am running it in a virtual environment making the virus acts freely then observing what happens.
but i am not going to run it in a virtual environment or a black sand box as some of the big companies was researching in, i am willing to detect it by emulating the code then observing what happened to the registers what system calls it called and so.
what is your opinion.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create an x86 emulator, you can have a look at this complete opcodes listing:
[x86 Instruction Set Reference](http://siyobik.info/index.php?module=x86). But it doesn't seem to be a good way to detect viruses.

Comment: Actually, it's an excellent way to do behavioral heuristics and stack-pattern matching. You can take some malware and identify the pattern of data it pushes to the stack during unpacking, then build a signature for that and emulate the app. If the pattern of push/pop is the same, it's a heuristic match. You just have to be clever enough to avoid traps (e.g. SEH tricks employing API calls at EP).

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for [Bochs](http://bochs.sourceforge.net/), an LGPL'ed emulator of the x86 ISA and common hardware.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing in the register values that indicates maliciousness. You better give up on that. What most sandboxes trying to detect malicious behavior do is intercepting the system/library calls.

call ftable+1 with context %eax=1 %ebx=4000 %ecx=3F could as well mean shoot nuclear missiles as it could mean print hello world.
Now if you put your own function between the system and the executable you can know what is going on(identifying it as malicious isn't as easy as that).

That certainly needs no emulator, so you better reconsider that as writing an accurate emulator is very, very hard.